# Exporting and Importing a list of Data Frames as json file in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has the DataFrame.to_json and pd.read_json functions that work for single Data Frames. However, I have been trying to figure a way to export and import a list with many Data Frames into and from a single json file. So far, I have come to successfully export the list with this code:

```
with open('my_file.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines([json.dumps(df.to_dict()) for df in list_of_df])
```

This creates a json file with all the Data Frames converted to dicts. However, when I try to do the reverse to read the file and extract my Data Frames, I get an error. This is the code:

```
with open('my_file.json', 'r') as outfile:
    list_of_df = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(item)) for item in 
    outfile]
```

The error I get is:
JSONDecodeError: Extra data

I think the problem is that I have to include somehow the opposite of 'writelines', which is 'readlines' in the code that reads the json file, but I do not know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `writelines` your data isn't really a list in the python sense, which makes reading it a bit tricky. I'd recommend instead writing to your file like this:

```py
with open('my_file.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps([df.to_dict() for df in list_of_df]))
```

Which means we can read it back just as simply using:

```py
with open('my_file.json', 'r') as outfile:
    list_of_df = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item) for item in json.loads(outfile.read())]
```

Comment: I am having a weird issue when I load the json file to read it back. The DataFrames are being indexed alphabetically, which is an inconvenient. Do you know why is this?

Comment: Depending on your version of python, the dict might not be guaranteed to be the same order that it was created in. I'm not sure if pandas can return an orderdict, but you might want to look into keeping the index. What does the `outfile` look like?

Comment: The outfile json is ordered as wanted. Actually, it is a bug in Pandas, which can be worked around by the manipulation 'orient=index' and then performing a Transposition. This keeps the indexes in their original position, but alters the order of the columns, which has to be reordered back. Here, more info: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8425